# Apparent resolution changes in browsers

Tags: html, css, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm having an extremely weird resolution problem and am hoping the tags are at least partially appropriate.

Here's what happens:
I have an image with size 1920x1080, my screen resolution is also 1920x1080 as indicated by the OS (Windows 8.1). Viewing the image in Windows Photo Viewer and clicking the button to make it "Actual size" makes it fill the entire screen from left to right, while being scrollable vertically, as expected.

I now use this image in a website/html file. I've tried both `<img>` and CSS `background-image`, resizing the element or the containing box to 1920x1080, no matter what I try, the image is too large and I see only about 2/3 of it horizontally. What's more, I've added a border to an absolutely positioned empty div and given that div `width: 1247px;` via CSS. The border goes nearly across the entire screen, leaving about 30 pixels on both sides combined, which leads me to the conclusion that for whatever reason, my browsers (tested in most recent versions of Firefox and Chrome) change their contents' resolution to 1280xsomething. Which I find very strange, especially since I'm using both of them in classical desktop mode and can freely display other windows on top of them without any graphical effects that usually happen when an application display its contents in a different resolution.

So, my questions are:

1. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?
2. How can I fix this and make my browsers use my screen's resolution?

Here's a simple setup that reproduces the issue in question. Save as `anyfilename.html`, set screen resolution to `1920x1080` in system settings, open the file in a browser:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background-image: url(http://www.hd-wallpapers.com/download/black-glass_1920x1080_225-hd.jpg);
      }

      div {
        border: 2px solid red;
        width: 1247px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your html and jss in a jsfiddle please

Comment: We really need to see the image and the markup to figure this out.

Comment: also, note that 1920 is HUGE on a web page. Few people will have a browser set to see it all.

Comment: @DA. You say "Few people will have a browser set to see it all". I think that's what I'm looking at. Do browsers use like a standard resolution below what screens do by default? I think that might be the problem's root.

Comment: Oh! I see what your issue is. Yes, if your background image is 1920 pixels wide, then your browser will also have to be 1920 pixels wide if you want to see it all. The browser isn't changing resolutions of any of your images. It's just that the browser window isn't large enough for you to see it all.

Comment: @DA. So basically, even if my system resolution is 1920x1080, my maximized browser window )or let's say its contents) is not necessarily 1920 pixels wide, but instead usually scaled down to 1280, if I understand it correctly. Is it safe to assume this is the case for all or most browsers out there? Are there any statistics on this?

Comment: @scenia there are all sorts of stats, but remember that your browser viewport is rarely the same size as your screen on desktops. Many people don't browser the internet with fully-maximized browser windows. And, of course, there's so many tablets and phones out there now-a-days as well. If you have to pick a size, most folks design sits that aren't much bigger than 1080 in width.

Comment: browser viewport was the keyword that was missing so I'd understand it, thank you very much for your help! In the long run, I'll have the website adapt to the user's viewport, but for the time being, I wanted to make sure it looks good on most browsers.